# Insert record into mysql with Jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, sql-update

I am n need of inserting / updating records when I drag and drop list items from one  to the other.
All is good, the list items are dragged and dropped around, however I can't get to update the database record.

Can anyone help me with this please? Very frustrating.

I have four `<ul>` tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    #sortable0,
    #sortable1,
    #sortable2,
    #sortable3 {
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 143px;
        min-height: 60px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #sortable0 {
        height: 10px !important;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $( function () {
        $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable( {
            connectWith: "ul",
            cursor: "move"
        } );

        $( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable( {
            connectWith: "ul",
            dropOnEmpty: false
        } );

        $( "#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
    } );
</script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<div id="response"> </div>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php 

        echo $_POST['sortie_id'];


        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <form>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="65%" nowrap="nowrap">Bir Sonraki Sorti :
                    <strong>
                        <?php echo $nextSortie; ?>
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td width="33%" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">Yolcu Say&#305;s&#305; :
                    <strong>
                        <?php echo $num_nSortieDetails; ?>
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td width="35%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <?php
                    // print the passenger list for the sortie
                    $pa = new PrintAnything();



                    $url = ( !isset( $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] ) || $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] != 'on' ? 'http://' : 'https://' );
                    $url .= $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] );
                    $url = trim( str_replace( '\\', '/', $url ) );
                    if ( substr( $url, -1 ) != '/' ) {
                        $url .= '/';
                    }
                    $url .= 'print_SortieList.php';
                    $printData3 = PrintAnything::readBody( $url );
                    $con3 = $pa->addPrintContext( $printData3 );

                    $pa->showPrintLink( $con3, '<button style="font-size:24px">Yazdır <i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>' );

                    //  end print stuff

                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <hr width="90%" size="1" color="#FFFFFF"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="65%" valign="top">

                    <div id="list">
                        <?php if($num_nSortieDetails > 0) { 

          ?>

                        <ul id="sortable0" class="droptrue">

                            <?php
                            do {
                                ?>

                            <li class="ui-state-default" id="arrayorder_<?php echo $id ?>">
                                <span class="noshow">
                                    <?php echo $row_nSortieDetails['id']; ?> </span>
                                <span class="psgr">
                                    <?php echo ucwords(strtolower($row_nSortieDetails['fullname'])); ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>

                            <?php 
          } while($row_nSortieDetails=mysqli_fetch_array($nSortieDetails));
    ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php
                        } // end if the recordset has results ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="35%" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F4CDCD">
                    <?php echo "pilot out : " . $pilot_out;
            ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">
                    <table width="75%" border="0" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="2" align="center">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Ocean Team</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Dragon Team</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center"><strong>Albatros Team</strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">

                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">

                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">

                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <?php $ops->TeamPilots("1", $db); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <?php $ops->TeamPilots("2", $db); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <?php $ops->TeamPilots("3", $db); ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </form>
</table>

<br style="clear:both">
```

I want to drag from 'sortable0' to either one of three

And I want the dragged record id to update in the relevant database.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You will need some server-sided backend, like an API to send anything to a database. I doubt that there is a possibility to directly connect to a database with jQuery and if there is a way to do that, I really would not suggest it.

Comment: There are similar examples on the internet, where you can SORT the list items and send the data to MySQL db.

http://papermashup.com/drag-drop-with-php-jquery/

My problem is that I fail to trigger the code that updates the db.

Comment: I assure you, that there is more involved than just jQuery and a database. The examples probably listen to an onChange event and trigger a call to an API which then updates the data in the given DB.

Comment: I managed to reach this level seen on the link:

http://www.irmakerol.com/drag/

I also managed to updated teh table one way. Now I need to get the list items to swicth both ways. At th emoment it only gets from the ul on teh left to the ul on th right and not vice versa